# Get tabulary with numerous footnotes generated by MultiMarkdown to break across pages - Incompatiblity between longtable and bigfoot

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, longtable, tabulary, bigfoot

I've been struggling a lot getting long (and sometimes wide) tables with numerous footnotes working.

Basically I'm generating numerous tables using MultiMarkdown, which produces tables using the `tabulary` package inside a `minipage` and inside a `table` enviroment (probably as a workaround to allow regular footnotes inside the table), generally of the following structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\tymax}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\small
\caption{Long table caption\footnote{test}.\label{long}}\\

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}ll@{}} \toprule
Something\footnote{test} & something else\\
\midrule

Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

These tables generally work fine up to a certain length, but they do not break across pages and if there are too many footnotes, they get pushed off the page. I can get around some of those limitations without rewriting the LaTeX code by putting them inside a `\begin{landscape}`-environment and modifying the page style and geometry as such:

```
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{plain}

... the actual table...

\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry{}
\reversemarginpar{}
```

But this workaround only works for tables which can shrink in length by growing wider. So I'm actually looking for a workaround requiring the least manipulation to the LaTeX code generated by MultiMarkdown (ideally using an environment I can simply wrap around the generated tables), and while looking for a way to get those tables working, I ran into this particular incompatibility in between `bigfoot` and `longtable`:

While trying to manually convert `tabulary` into a table format which supports breaking across pages, I read that `longtable` had good footnote support. For now, I've refrained from using the `tabu`-package, since I read it was not maintained, and I've had less luck getting `tablex` to work (e.g. together with `ltablex`, but I've read about other options).

Currently I'm trying to use the `longtable`-package together with `pdflscape`, however I noted that it does not compile when I use `bigfoot`-package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |}
\caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
\hline
Something & something else\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long}}\\
\hline
Something & something else\\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endfoot

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
\hline\hline
\endlastfoot

Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
Lots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

On a local machine it sometimes compiles after a long time (while it always times out on Overleaf), with an error message and a PDF of thousands of pages:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. 
>   \footinsdefault 
>                               l.76 L
>         ots of lines \footnote{test} & like this \footnote{test}\ If you really absolutely need more capacity, you can ask a wizard to
>   enlarge me.

However the MWE compiles fine on both a local machine and Overleaf if I comment out `\usepackage{bigfoot}`.

I've tried using, the `footmisc` package with the `para` option (`\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`) instead, but then the footnotes disappear entirely and the footnotemarks get overlayed, resulting in one big black block at the lower left end of the page.

I assume these issues may be relevant to the maintainers of those packages (particularly the error in between `bigfoot` and `longtable`), however I would be glad for a simple (but stable) workaround for my actual issue with those MultiMarkdown-generated tables.

Comment: each of `table`, `minipage` and `tabulary` generate an unbreakable box, so you have three nested unbreakable boxes and need to remove them all if you want to allow page breaking, so changing the generator not to generate that form would be a good start.

Comment: I can confirm the loop with bigfoot but can;t look now. This quote from The TeXBook may help:-)   `Don't use footnotes in your books, Don. \author JILL ^{KNUTH} (1962)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, I can't think of a structure, where I don't need footnotes in tables. And just to clarify, I'm not looking to fork the MultiMarkdown generator, but I'm looking for a simple way to modify the generated code, either by wrapping the table inside a new LaTeX environment (as with the landscape-example), or alternatively by running RegEx replacements on the generated LaTeX code before compilation. But for either I need a working LaTeX structure, which breaks tables across pages and handles footnotes correctly.

Comment: Do you currently try to use the `bigfoot` package due to all the footnotes inside of the longtable or do you also need it for other footnotes in your document. If you definitely need something like footnotes inside of the longtable envrionment, you could take a look at the `threeparttablex` package in order to get tablenotes instead of footnotes.

Comment: @leandriis Without `bigfoot` I'm getting errors placing examples using `gb4e` inside footnotes (and I need paragraph-style footnotes and `footmisc` produces other errors as mentioned above). `threeparttablex` sounds like a good option if I set tables manually. However, I can't imagine an easy way to convert the existing `tabulary`s into that format - while I could wrap a `longtable` around the existing tables and remove the `tabulary` enviroment, I'm not seeing a (semi-)automatic way to extract all of the footnotes from the table, move them up-front and replace them by `\tnote`s

Comment: @leandriis FYI, I've been experimenting with `threeparttablex, but I'm seeing other issues with footnotemarks overlapping, as [raised in a separate post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550902/threeparttablex-tnotes-overlap-overlay-with-cell-content).