# Threeparttablex \tnote's overlap / overlay with cell content

Tags: tablenotes, threeparttablex, overlap

I'm experimenting with `threeparttablex` for some long and wide tables. I'm using roman-numbers (**NB Based on the comments I updated the MWE to use letters, but the issue persists**) for the `\tnote` marks and noticed that the `\tnote` marks overlap / overlay with sequential text inside the same table cell, if `\tnote` marks become longer. I was looking for related issues, but could only find [cases, in which users were trying to attach several `\tnote` marks to the same cell content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388376/how-to-put-multiple-table-notes-in-one-cell-using-threepartablex?rq=1). Here however, I'm having several strings in the same cell with several `\tnote`s for each string:

[image: MWE]

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,flushleft,online]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
test

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
\item[jj] `test'
\item[kk] `test'
            \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lllllllll@{}}
        \caption{test}\\
            \toprule
            test & \multicolumn{2}{c}{test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{test} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{test}\\
                    & test                        & test                   & test                        & test & test & test \\
            \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \endhead

            \cmidrule{2-7}
        \endfoot
            \addlinespace
            \bottomrule
            \insertTableNotes\\
            \midrule
        \endlastfoot

test  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{test\tnote{jj} test\tnote{kk}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \ensuremath{\emptyset}                               } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \ensuremath{\emptyset}     }\\

    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

test

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: That is what `\tnote` does, you should not he using such long labels in the first place and should not add a space in front either. `\tnote` is designed to be added at the end of cells without disturbing alignment

Comment: @daleif Thank you for pointing out the extra spaces. I removed them from the MWE, but the issue persists. I'm still looking for a way to have multiple footnotes to multiple strings in cells, in a table which breaks across pages, and `threeparttablex` was suggested as a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548141/get-tabulary-with-numerous-footnotes-generated-by-multimarkdown-to-break-across). But I'd be glad for any other suggestions you may have for alternatives to 'threeparttablex'!

Comment: it still allows you seveal notes, but you will have to insert spacve manually if it comes between words. `\tnote{}` is similar to `\rlap{\textsuperscript{...}}`, where `\rlap` is a macro that inserts stuff on the right of where it is in a manner that takes up no space.

Comment: You probably need to be more explicit in what exactly it is you want to do. Those very long note names is certainly not a good idea

Comment: @daleif As I wrote above, what I'm exacty trying to do is "I'm looking for a way to have multiple footnotes to multiple strings in cells, in a table wihich breaks across pages", with a more detailed backgrounded in the [linked post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548141/get-tabulary-with-numerous-footnotes-generated-by-multimarkdown-to-break-across), but kindly let me know what is not explicit in that - I'm a comparatively recent user of LaTeX. I could use Arabic instead of Roman numbers, but then then the `\tnote`s, would not be visually differentiated from regular `\footnote`s.

Comment: that is why I use lower case letters

Comment: Why not use letters instead of numbers for the table notes?

Comment: @daleif have updated the MWE to use letters, but the issue persists.

Comment: As I mentioned if the not is note at the end of the cell you need to insert spacing your self for example one or several `\ ` (backslash space).